# JS match list item color with selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `.title` color to match the selected `.cat-item` but I can't figure out how to work it into my code.

```js
var $container = $(".cat-dropdown-menu"),
  $list = $(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-list"),
  listItem = $list.find(".cat-item");

$(".cat-dropdown .title").click(function() {
  if ($container.height() > 0) {
    closeMenu(this);
  } else {
    openMenu(this);
  }
});

$(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item").click(function() {
  closeMenu(this);
});

function closeMenu(el) {
  $(el)
    .closest(".cat-dropdown")
    .toggleClass("closed")
    .find(".title")
    .text($(el).text());
  $container.css("height", 0);
  $list.css("top", 0);
}

function openMenu(el) {
  $(el)
    .parent()
    .toggleClass("closed");

  $container.css({
    height: 200
  });
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* OPTIONS */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat-dropdown {
  text-align: left;
  color: #343c3f;
  border: 1px solid #a2acb0;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item {
  height: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title:after {
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .title {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
}

.cat-dropdown .title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "▾";
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: "border-box";
  -moz-box-sizing: "border-box";
  box-sizing: "border-box";
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
  padding: 0 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item:hover {
  background-color: #d9e1e4;
  color: #343c3f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="title">Pick user</div>
  <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="cat-list">
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#3772b1">Henry Christensen</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#4eaddc">Lamar Flynn</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#ff9148">Jameson Davidson</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.css('color', el.style.color);`:

```js
var $container = $(".cat-dropdown-menu"),
  $list = $(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-list"),
  listItem = $list.find(".cat-item");

$(".cat-dropdown .title").click(function() {
  if ($container.height() > 0) {
    closeMenu(this);
  } else {
    openMenu(this);
  }
});

$(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item").click(function() {
  closeMenu(this);
});

function closeMenu(el) {
  $(el)
    .closest(".cat-dropdown")
    .toggleClass("closed")
    .find(".title")
    .text($(el).text())
    .css('color', el.style.color);
  $container.css("height", 0);
  $list.css("top", 0);
}

function openMenu(el) {
  $(el)
    .parent()
    .toggleClass("closed");

  $container.css({
    height: 200
  });
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* OPTIONS */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat-dropdown {
  text-align: left;
  color: #343c3f;
  border: 1px solid #a2acb0;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item {
  height: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title:after {
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .title {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
}

.cat-dropdown .title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "▾";
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: "border-box";
  -moz-box-sizing: "border-box";
  box-sizing: "border-box";
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
  padding: 0 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item:hover {
  background-color: #d9e1e4;
  color: #343c3f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="title">Pick user</div>
  <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="cat-list">
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#3772b1">Henry Christensen</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#4eaddc">Lamar Flynn</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#ff9148">Jameson Davidson</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look  at the code added in closemenu()

```js
var $container = $(".cat-dropdown-menu"),
  $list = $(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-list"),
  listItem = $list.find(".cat-item");
  

$(".cat-dropdown .title").click(function() {
  if ($container.height() > 0) {
    closeMenu(this);
  } else {
    openMenu(this);
  }
});

$(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item").click(function() {
  closeMenu(this);
});

function closeMenu(el) {
  $(el)
  
  
    .closest(".cat-dropdown")
    .toggleClass("closed")
    .find(".title")
    .text($(el).text());
    
    
  $container.css("height", 0);
  document.getElementById('pick').style.color = el.style.color;
  $list.css("top", 0);
}

function openMenu(el) {
  $(el)
    .parent()
    .toggleClass("closed");
    
  //  console.log(el)

  $container.css({
    height: 200
  });
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* OPTIONS */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat-dropdown {
  text-align: left;
  color: #343c3f;
  border: 1px solid #a2acb0;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item {
  height: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title:after {
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .title {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
}

.cat-dropdown .title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "▾";
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: "border-box";
  -moz-box-sizing: "border-box";
  box-sizing: "border-box";
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
  padding: 0 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item:hover {
  background-color: #d9e1e4;
  color: #343c3f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div id='pick' class="title">Pick user</div>
  <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="cat-list">
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#3772b1">Henry Christensen</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#4eaddc">Lamar Flynn</li>
      <li class="cat-item" style="color:#ff9148">Jameson Davidson</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```